# #docusignAPI Static IP address and ports of the DocuSign API services

Tags: docusignapi

We have been facing some connectivity issues in establishing the connection with the DocuSign API services for a sandbox account. The firewall within the network from which we are trying to access the services is blocking the outgoing requests. To open the ports in the firewall we would like to know the static IP address and ports of the sandbox account.
https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/trust-certifications/whitelist/ for the current list.

Note that the list is updated frequently, so you will need to track it.

Comment: Thanks Larry. Could you also tell us the ports through which the requests would go through when we try to establish a connection with the DocuSign API services.

Comment: When your app makes a call to DocuSign, port is 443. When DocuSign calls you, connect notifications, the port is random.